# passing port to calibre-server via env variable in upstart script

Tags: upstart, calibre

I'm trying to write an upstart script for [calibre-server](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/calibre-server.html).

I can add all the arguments I need using env variables except for --port.

```
description "Calibre (ebook manager) content server"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]

respawn

env USER='test'
env PASSWORD='test'
env LIBRARY_PATH='/var/lib/calibre'
env NAME='calibre-server'
env DAEMON='/usr/bin/$NAME'
env MAX_COVER='300x400'
env PORT='80'

env ARGS='--auto-reload --max-cover $MAX_COVER --port $PORT'

exec /usr/bin/calibre-server --with-library $LIBRARY_PATH $ARGS --username $USER --password $PASSWORD
```

Using the above script, if I run `start calibre-server` it fails to start and in `/var/log/upstart/calibre-server.log` I get 
**calibre-server: error: option --port: invalid integer value: u'$PORT'**

Removing the quotes to change the declaration to `env PORT=80` doesn't help.

Changing the ARGS to `env ARGS='--auto-reload --max-cover $MAX_COVER --port 80'` works perfectly, but isn't ideal as I'd like to keep all the variables consistently declared separately.

Any help greatly appreciated. Also the first upstart script I've written so shouting out about anything else that's obviously wrong with it would be nice.

I'm using a new install of Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It cannot interpolate into an integer, check if `${PORT}` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how MAX_COVER is working, but variables do not expand in env stanzas. For example, take the following job:

```
env US=yhej
env SU="$US"

exec echo $US $SU
```

If variables expanded, this would output:

```
yhej yhej
```

but instead, it outputs:

```
yhej $US
```

You can modify your job to use a script section and variables will be expanded:

```
description "Calibre (ebook manager) content server"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]

respawn

env USER='test'
env PASSWORD='test'
env LIBRARY_PATH='/var/lib/calibre'
env MAX_COVER='300x400'
env PORT='80'

script
    exec /usr/bin/calibre-server --with-library $LIBRARY_PATH --auto-reload \
                                 --max-cover $MAX_COVER --port $PORT \
                                 --username $USER --password $PASSWORD
end script
```